# Assistant Professor vs Assistant Teaching Professor

Tags: job, assistant-professor

Is there any difference between an "Assistant Professor" position and "Assistant Teaching Professor"?

Answer (score 9):

"Assistant Teaching Professor" isn't a very common title, and the meaning of the title could vary from one institution to another.  However, I would assume that an "assistant teaching professor" was a position for someone whose responsibilities included only teaching and perhaps some service but no research.  In that case, it would most likely not be a tenure track position.

The two important factors here are whether the position has both teaching and research responsibilities and whether or not it's a tenure track position.

Comment: It might help to clarify the more standard term, "Assistant Professor", in terms of tenure status and research vs. teaching priority.